# How do I clear values from text_field_tag after browser refresh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue with text_field_tag. I want to reset the value of
the text_field when I refresh my browser, seems like a very simple
thing, however I'm having hard time finding the answer.

After I input some values, how do i reset the value to nil or empty??

my code is below

```
<%= text_field_tag 'access_code', nil,
%>
```

Any help or tip will be greatly appreciated.

This is my session new page and access_code which I enter in text field is define in config.yml file.
If I don't enter any access code in text field still I get the value in my controller which I enter last time...how can I reset the value?......

Thanks in advance!

logs- 
:

```
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-09 16:14:26 +0530
I, [2015-06-09T16:14:26.368484 #6707]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
I, [2015-06-09T16:14:26.368731 #6707]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Dw7fO0ZyO4/ZPnNknuXbt4xsLkGWlxM3rmaEYvClTDRjq0dLdVUGt84Pw2ZNBQ8Sz2x7BGZwlHCmq3EozDmoJg==", "access_code"=>"12345", "login"=>"admin", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in"}
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:26.372837 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `sessions`.* FROM `sessions` WHERE `sessions`.`session_id` = '261e811b132a8cf574d6733a2bf5a2f4'  ORDER BY `sessions`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
I, [2015-06-09T16:14:26.376843 #6707]  INFO -- : checking for Mobile Device - Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.81 Safari/537.1
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:39.505665 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mSQL (1.1ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.`id` AS t0_r0, `users`.`login` AS t0_r1, `users`.`email` AS t0_r2, `users`.`encrypted_password` AS t0_r3, `users`.`password_salt` AS t0_r4, `users`.`created_at` AS t0_r5, `users`.`updated_at` AS t0_r6, `users`.`remember_token` AS t0_r7, `users`.`remember_token_expires_at` AS t0_r8, `users`.`reset_password_token` AS t0_r9, `users`.`enabled` AS t0_r10, `users`.`customer_id` AS t0_r11, `users`.`status` AS t0_r12, `users`.`plain_password` AS t0_r13, `users`.`last_checked_at` AS t0_r14, `users`.`sign_in_count` AS t0_r15, `users`.`current_sign_in_at` AS t0_r16, `users`.`last_sign_in_at` AS t0_r17, `users`.`current_sign_in_ip` AS t0_r18, `users`.`last_sign_in_ip` AS t0_r19, `users`.`created_by` AS t0_r20, `users`.`failed_attempts` AS t0_r21, `users`.`disable_reason` AS t0_r22, `customers`.`id` AS t1_r0, `customers`.`name` AS t1_r1, `customers`.`customer_type` AS t1_r2, `customers`.`parent_id` AS t1_r3, `customers`.`created_at` AS t1_r4, `customers`.`updated_at` AS t1_r5, `customers`.`meta_data` AS t1_r6, `customers`.`opt_out` AS t1_r7, `customers`.`fulfilled` AS t1_r8, `customers`.`complete` AS t1_r9, `customers`.`fulfillment_issue` AS t1_r10, `customers`.`deleted_at` AS t1_r11, `customers`.`generic_bulletin` AS t1_r12, `customers`.`archived` AS t1_r13, `customers`.`vendor_rep` AS t1_r14, `customers`.`vendor_rep_email` AS t1_r15, `customers`.`vendor_rep_phone_no` AS t1_r16, `customers`.`converted_to_new_year` AS t1_r17, `customers`.`fulfillment_info` AS t1_r18, `customers`.`slug` AS t1_r19, `customers`.`start_date` AS t1_r20, `customers`.`end_date` AS t1_r21, `customers`.`bcc_on_confirmation` AS t1_r22, `customers`.`sales_tax_type` AS t1_r23, `customers`.`sales_tax_rate` AS t1_r24, `customers`.`delta` AS t1_r25, `customers`.`time_zone` AS t1_r26, `customers`.`commission_perc_req_items` AS t1_r27, `customers`.`commission_perc_optional_items` AS t1_r28, `customers`.`commission_perc_spirit_items` AS t1_r29, `customers`.`commission_perc_blended_rate` AS t1_r30, `customers`.`credit_card_processing_rate` AS t1_r31, `customers`.`monthly_service_fee` AS t1_r32, `customers`.`annual_service_fee` AS t1_r33, `customers`.`store_building_fee` AS t1_r34, `customers`.`account_setup_fee` AS t1_r35, `customers`.`fee_calculated_pre_tax` AS t1_r36, `customers`.`fee_calculated_post_tax` AS t1_r37, `customers`.`handling_fee` AS t1_r38, `customers`.`advertisement` AS t1_r39, `customers`.`payment_receiver_override` AS t1_r40, `customers`.`banner_image` AS t1_r41, `customers`.`default_payment_receiver` AS t1_r42, `customers`.`handling_fee_type` AS t1_r43, `customers`.`support_email_address` AS t1_r44, `customers`.`discount_per_order` AS t1_r45, `customers`.`discount_per_order_min_amount` AS t1_r46, `customers`.`player_number_required` AS t1_r47, `customers`.`discount_text` AS t1_r48, `customers`.`discount_max_counts` AS t1_r49, `customers`.`discount_coupon_code` AS t1_r50, `customers`.`accept_check` AS t1_r51, `customers`.`accept_credit_card` AS t1_r52, `customers`.`store_shipping_rates` AS t1_r53, `customers`.`mobile_version_enabled` AS t1_r54, `customers`.`reminder_email` AS t1_r55, `customers`.`returning_player` AS t1_r56, `customers`.`edit_order_after_closed` AS t1_r57, `customers`.`custom_text_for_receipt` AS t1_r58, `customers`.`eligibility_check_for_free_items` AS t1_r59, `customers`.`eligible_for_free_items` AS t1_r60, `customers`.`storefront_intro` AS t1_r61, `customers`.`pickup_locations` AS t1_r62, `customers`.`enable_facebook` AS t1_r63, `customers`.`allow_customer_notes_storefront` AS t1_r64, `customers`.`accept_cash` AS t1_r65, `customers`.`fb_page_id` AS t1_r66, `customers`.`league_enabled` AS t1_r67, `customers`.`status` AS t1_r68, `customers`.`agree_store_terms` AS t1_r69, `customers`.`launch_store` AS t1_r70, `customers`.`allow_shipping` AS t1_r71, `customers`.`amex_payment_method` AS t1_r72, `customers`.`copied_start_fresh_from` AS t1_r73, `customers`.`custom_message` AS t1_r74 FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `customers` ON `customers`.`id` = `users`.`customer_id` WHERE `users`.`login` = 'admin' AND `customers`.`deleted_at` IS NULL  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
I, [2015-06-09T16:14:39.511565 #6707]  INFO -- : Authentication:: Failed Login for User ID 1 Failed Login Attempts set to 2
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:39.512570 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:39.527978 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mUser Exists (0.9ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`login` = 'admin' AND `users`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:39.534245 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE `users` SET `failed_attempts` = 2, `updated_at` = '2015-06-09 10:44:39.514661' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1[0m
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:39.611739 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (73.7ms)[0m  COMMIT
I, [2015-06-09T16:14:39.623991 #6707]  INFO -- :   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.1ms)
I, [2015-06-09T16:14:42.294270 #6707]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 15925ms (Views: 2680.0ms | ActiveRecord: 77.4ms)
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:42.295683 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:42.302890 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  UPDATE `sessions` SET `data` = 'BAh7CUkiEmRvbWFpbl92ZW5kb3IGOgZFRkkiB25hBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rv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\n', `updated_at` = '2015-06-09 10:44:42.298136' WHERE `sessions`.`id` = 45
D, [2015-06-09T16:14:42.363066 #6707] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (58.4ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
```

Comment: Where is your @login come from, from your controller? then everytime you hydrate the page it will get called back again. So why do you need to reset it if you are calling it? Can I please see your controller?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look again.

Comment: Can you please show me the log after your form been submitted?

Comment: rquired :true is working as per my expectation no worries now I have to put anything in the text field. <%= text_field_tag 'access_code', nil, class: "asterisk_input", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'off', required: true %>

Answer (score 0):

its its a js request,then you need to explicitly use jquery to make all text fields html as empty as you are using `javascript` to submit a form and **NOT** `html` which would have caused a total page refresh by using `redirect_to: new_session_url`.So in your `login` method,you must use something like:-

```
def login
##save the user info
respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
end

login.js.erb
 $("#login-textbox").val(" ");
```

**OR, YOU CAN ADD PAGE SPECIFIC JAVASCRIPT TO CLEAR TEXTBOXES ONSUBMIT**

```
//add this js in your page 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
        var isValid = true;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                isValid = false;
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "1px solid red",
                    "background": "#FFCECE"
                });
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "",
                    "background": ""
                });
            }
        });
        if (isValid == false) 
            e.preventDefault();
        else 
            alert('Thank you for submitting');
    });
});
```